# QtCreator on Windows: No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, qt-creator

I have Visual Studio 2019, CMake 3.18.4, Ninja 1.10.1, Qt 5.15.0, QtCreator 4.13.2, and I'm trying to open a Qt/CMake project with QtCreator.

I get this output from CMake:

```
2020-12-02T17:04:23 Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.
Running C:\Dev\Libs\Qt-5.15\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe -S C:/Dev/test1 -B C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-GpQBVK/qtc-cmake-tnApaSrE -GNinja "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String=Debug" "-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=C:/Dev/Libs/Qt-5.15/5.15.0/msvc2019_64/bin/qmake.exe" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=C:/Dev/Libs/Qt-5.15/5.15.0/msvc2019_64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=" in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-GpQBVK\qtc-cmake-tnApaSrE.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-GpQBVK/qtc-cmake-tnApaSrE/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-GpQBVK/qtc-cmake-tnApaSrE/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake process exited with exit code 1.
Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

regardless of which *CMake Tool* is selected in the Kit configuration (I can choose from **CMake 3.18.3 (Qt)** and **System CMake at C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe**)

The kit configuration shows a warning sign, although it is not clear what is the problem:

[image]

The obvious problem seems to be that the argument `"-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="` is passed to CMake (empty string).

But the C and C++ compilers are set in the kit.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by **upgrading** via the Qt maintenance tool.

Comment: Just clarification: I've updated Qt from 5.12.4 to 5.12.10 and it seems to have fixed the issue. I doubt that it's Qt version related, rather the act of updating Qt fixed whatever was broken.